# Reference: Result of interior parabolic regularity theory for Hamilton–Jacobi equations

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, parabolic-pde

Does anyone know the parabolic regularity result that Ben-Artzi used in the article [The local theory for viscous Hamilton–Jacobi equations in Lebesgue spaces](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/271968/1-s2.0-S0021782400X00517/1-s2.0-S0021782401012430/main.pdf?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEM%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJIMEYCIQDfH01H6H%2FsOo%2F1T8v7j4hGWgmMHNUtaKXvcGG7jBcOlwIhANm0OR%2BkatNRC%2Fjc%2BYTNUEUU1muT8AexJ9HGjfNWA4gxKrsFCPf%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEQBRoMMDU5MDAzNTQ2ODY1Igx3zRjjePvmXvNfG%2FMqjwVVTJGgdTgNHQjaSTR0lhvYak1BFKBHliCo0Z%2BjJtUMVLSimp5XUaU%2FKz%2BcQxyaRAK8fKhhdQXexAs7hAxDrsNekIXb1rP5LPj%2BILZTH34p1%2BhfXKeysg2mcessCdvKavwQTNZDR%2BHc4Mm7%2FqK51bC16NaPVYP3UGa0uH0M2FYBBXoTUq1FKbFsrA3HGkl%2BoKownUle%2BZoPasrSaMR3etqhNsr5oWTZN9P%2FuU6DO5XEa2r9ThII5zdRCR4XdGIpwPrYcbW2TmJcOJFGVumnSuzMqsEcd639mSDAYyceVxGruBCgo2Yxy%2BaXAXxGCL7e2W9r1iyMP2TtR2DnUgWxg4J1vR88J7RuyDH6BaZRis%2Bwhyl98QIps3DLqv%2B3GlffrLxWNvn7V39xd%2BdxBiECVqBcZ5O92QEsh0vqQ7fOYbPRqNx8%2B7FM%2BGSN7p3VvaxBshDPSE6LfWHrbg1LemzGrEQfgcn8gQex1SxUT%2FnioXmghJPuTe9jMi%2F3hzd9tYjCkiDsa55YSTv7wXxyvHC9L4z8ScnmckG0wZwUFPKpj2K%2BeX80bPvS9YgUMdZCpMNeSRV1TXgKw1D3HsqKH19BBsQ%2BDmi%2BBIhAvUfFesS3MxKKEbyGbRkswjgLbjj3OmWqhJZLLSiBGernmbyKclrxB7Hq6nts6gM1zfyGJXi4pi0RSag3sO8XYv%2FyW8R3mJUWji4lvtiF6XDTrtZ7RAnVa8YYPH9LVLx5e1ZVlHVHfruz2Uuf2gc7tapgW%2FH4XZUEO4wDX0K962Y%2BgsRP%2BLgtmJsGmu%2BdQEjeqsaZ6Y0XI%2B1rqmVrA6pppU4LweFkpTTcYAKfi%2B%2FdrrFhVFodUx3gHavHfcWpBLcJ6cTQ5DQa5WbMMImbuqMGOrABSgISsGg6RKTMqyxrBJWf7JU07N%2FEmysajjytR6RP9DJMSQB0pm5IvrEgp9o1issNyqjqnxuMn9TU4Fgd197v6fcVXIQihOlxZFs93Zs%2FML%2B9jlh9XrEO10x1rrcsxbvj4d5Mtd7J%2FsC%2FDLstxpjgWK%2FLzR90eaPQvw2n%2Fa6jiE0ZRNUtDpVepFThBhvlhScccJoQXfs59AEsUyoryBn96vABVef9IfBkPQBl2y53dYA%3D&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20230524T230817Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3PHCVTY5QLDPYNJ%2F20230524%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=b50bedb564188b2c647d36500bf72d9e0464ee5c42c39aed8462a57e755cea9e&hash=0fbc0136a3b037e545d0196b4514219382cd7979ac162e7b0fc6bdd3544381b1&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=S0021782401012430&tid=spdf-1bcfcaa8-40f0-4b8e-8336-33ebe1941451&sid=bd733d964b4e92431228e90-ddd2e98b883egxrqa&type=client&tsoh=d3d3LnNjaWVuY2VkaXJlY3QuY29t&ua=041459050d5a575c5153&rr=7cc93320586b00c3&cc=br) used to prove that the solution to the problem is classical?

he studies the equation
\begin{equation}
        \left\{ 
        \begin{array}{rll}
            u_t -  \Delta u &=  |\nabla u|^{p}& \mbox{ in } \mathbb{R}^n \times (0,T), \\   
            {u}(0) &=  {u}_{0}& \mbox{ in } \mathbb{R}^n, \\
        \end{array}
        \right.
    \end{equation}

and shows the global existence of a mild solution. On page 354 (Completion of proof of Theorem 2.1 ) he says: By standard arguments using interior parabolic regularity theory (see, e.g., [42, Theorem 7.13]) (Lieberman Book), along with $u ∈ C((0,T_{max});W^{1,\infty})$, one easily obtains that $u \in C^{2,1}(Q_T )$ so that that u is a classical solution. But I couldn't find this result he is citing, can anyone reference this result?

Comment: Are you saying you can't find a copy of Lieberman's book? Not sure how to help with that. This kind of regularity result (parabolic Schauder theorem) is completely standard, I'm sure you can find it in any other parabolic reference (like Ladyzheskaya, Uraltseva, Solonnikov).

Comment: That's not it, I have a copy of Liberman, but I didn't find the result that Ben Artzi indicated, so I don't know if it's because I have a newer edition, or because he misreferenced it.

Comment: I see, indeed that reference seems unreasonable for the edition I have (apparently Chapter 7 was rewritten between editions though). I think you could use Theorem 4.8 (or the theorems in Chapter 6, or even the $L^p$ theorems in Chapter 7) repeatedly instead: first with $g$ being your RHS, which is bounded, to give $u \in C^{1, \alpha}$ (parabolic). Now your RHS is in $C^{0, \alpha}$ so differentiate the equation (or take difference quotients) in space and use $f_i$ as your RHS; this now gives $\nabla u \in C^{1, \alpha}$. You can also do this in time using difference quotients.

Answer (score 0):

I only found the result for $p=2$

- Herbert Amann, Existence and stability of solutions for semi-linear parabolic systems, and applications to some diffusion reaction equations, Theorem 3.1.

Since the operator $\partial_t -\Delta$ is uniformly parabolic, the solution of

$u_t-\Delta u=|\nabla f(x,t)|^p$

is smooth (by the fundamental solution). Then we need to find a fixed point of the map $f\mapsto u$ in $C^2$-space. Since the nonlinear first-order term and the linear second-order term have a "competition" relationship, in order to ensure the "semi-linear" property of the equation, the first-order term can not grow too fast.

Consider the more general case

$\mathcal L u=f(x,u,u_x),$

where $\mathcal L$ is an uniformly parabolic oprerator, and $|f(x,u,p)|\leq C(u)(1+|p|^2)$. The solution is still classical.

I think we can prove this result for more general $f$, which is just superlinear (that is, $p>1$). Once we get the Lipschitz estimation of the solution, then
we can modify $f$ outside of a big ball as we want (to make it be quadratic). To get a Lipschitz estimate, the super-linearity is enough. In fact, if $p\leq 2$, the proof is finished. Otherwise, let $R>0$ be the bound we get by the Bernstein method (it is not valid yet), then we can modify the Hamiltonian outside $|p|\geq R$ to be quadratic. Then the Bernstein method becomes valid, and the Lipschitz constant of solutions is unchanged. Then we can get the classical solutions for the original equation.